# Using Python 2.7, how can I fix this code so the program multiplies 64 on the weekdays to each result, and 80 on the weekends to each result?

Tags: python, python-2.7

- This is my code:

  ```
  days=["Sunday: ", "Monday: ", "Tuesday: ", "Wednesday: ", "Thursday: ", "Friday: ", "Saturday: "]
  Wdays=["Monday: ", "Tuesday: ", "Wednesday: ", "Thursday: ", "Friday: "]
  Wends=["Sunday: ", "Saturday: "]
  demand=[]
  temp=[]
  demand=[15, 20, 25, 18, 20, 22, 14]
  while demand[0]>0 or demand[1]>0 or demand[2]>0 or demand[3]>0 or demand[4]>0 or demand[5]>0 or demand[6]>0:
      min1=min(demand)
      ind1=demand.index(min1)
      temp=demand.copy()
      temp[ind1]=100000
      min2=min(temp)
      ind2=temp.index(min2)
      for i in range(7):
          if i != ind1 and i != ind2:
              demand[i]-=1
      print(demand)
  for e in range(7):
      while demand[e]:
          if Wdays:
              demand[e]-=1*64
          else:
              demand[e]-=1*80
  print(demand[e])`
  ```
- There appears to be a mistake in the second part of the code:

  ```
  for e in range(7):
      while demand[e]:
          if Wdays:
              demand[e]-=1*64
          else:
              demand[e]-=1*80
  print(demand[e])
  ```
- However I cannot find it. The goal is to output this, for example:

  ```
  [15, 19, 24, 17, 19, 21, 14]
  Weekdays: $6400
  Weekends: $2320
  ```
- Where it sums the digits in (1 through 5) and multiplies them by
  64 and then sums the digits in (0 and 6) and multiplies them by

Comment: why do you substract 64 or 80 from your value?

Comment: `if Wdays:` is always `True` as `Wdays` is a non empty list .. what do you want to do here?

Comment: You never print either `'Weekdays:'` nor `'Weekends:'` ... you only ever print demand[e] .. no idea how you think your output should be accomplished - especially because your last `while demand[e]:` is an endless loop - demand[e] never is 0 which would be a Falsy value

Comment: I want to fix the second part of my code because it's wrong. I want to organize/change it so it outputs first the sum of digits(1-5) which are then multiplied by 64 and second the sum of digits(0 and 6) which are then multiplied by 80. You can delete the second part of the code completely if you want because clearly it's just wrong.

Comment: so `print( sum(demand[1:6])*64, sum(demand)*80)` ?

Comment: I don't subtract 64 or 80, or atleast i'm not supposed to, the code is wrong clearly (my apologies for that). What I am trying to accomplish at the end of my code is to, after it prints the first part of my code I want the program to take each line it printed and sum digits(1-5)and multiply them by 64. To later sum digits(0 and 6) and then multiply them by 80.

Comment: @PatrickArtner it didn't work. It outputs a TypeError